# Unable to load the simple nodejs application on Windows - How to troubleshoot?

Tags: node.js

I have written the below code

```
 `use strict`;
  const express = require(`express`);

  //constansts
  const PORT = 7777;
  const HOST = `0.0.0.0`;

  //App
  const app = express();
  app.get(`/`,(req,res) => {
      res.send(`hello from nodejs`)
  });

  app.listen(PORT,HOST);
  console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

Outcome

[image]

This is my package.json

```
 {
  "name": "samplenodejsserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.18.2"
 }
```

}

**UPDATE**

It's working at HTTP ://127.0.0.1:7777
But not at HTTP ://0.0.0.0:7777

Comment: Are you trying to reach the node app from the machine where you have started it? How did you started it? What does the console print? Add a error handler to catch error events. Try it with "127.0.0.1:7777" in your browser instead of "0.0.0.0:7777" There are many possibility why its not working. Add more details.

Comment: Yes, it's loading from 127.0.0.1:7777   - Yes, I am trying to access from same machine

Comment: Is your browser chrome? Perhaps chrome blocks the IP "0.0.0.0" because its "not a real ip" and has a special meaning for sockets, it means "listen on all IPv4 interfaces".

Comment: Yes, it's chrome

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP. Specifying this as host to listen on only means that it will listen on all interfaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No access to http://0.0.0.0:8000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68067843/no-access-to-http-0-0-0-08000)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478747/why-does-ruby-on-rails-use-http-0-0-0-03000-instead-of-http-localhost3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP 0.0.0.0 is just a wildcard which tells the server to listen at **any** IP, but you still have to enter a IP which points to your PC.